# React PageYOffset not Changing or Updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make my navigation change after the user scrolls down. Currently, I am simply console logging the value of `window.pageYOffset`, however it only ever logs the value **0**. What am I doing wrong here?

```
export default class NavContainer extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      windowPosition: window.pageYOffset,
    };
  }

  handleScroll() {
    this.setState({windowPosition: window.pageYOffset});
    console.log(this.state.windowPosition);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll.bind(this));
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll.bind(this));
  }
}
```

EDIT: Easy fix, turned out to be a typo that is now corrected. Will leave it up for reference if anyone needs it.

Comment: your `handleScroll` is setting the `window.pageYOffset` value to `windowWidth`, not `windowPosition`

Comment: Haha, that would do it. Thanks.